# Char Pointer address assigned to address of integer pointer

Tags: c++, c, pointers

I'm trying to do something very simple, at least I thought, with no success.  I would like to assign the address pointed to by an integer pointer to the address pointed to by a char pointer.  Example

```
//C++

int *pointerint;
char *pointerchar;
pointerchar = pointerint;

//
```

I've tried to do this severals different ways without success.

Example:

```
pointerchar = (char *) &pointerint;
```

The compiler excepts it but the address assigned to the pointer is zero.  That can not be correct.  Can anyone tell me how to do this correctly and what I am doing wrong.  Thanks in advance for all your help.

Comment: This is indeed very simple to do as you can see from the answers ... but why do you want to do it? It's a generally dangerous operation, especially in the hands a rookie.

Answer (score 3):

Try (if C):

```
pointerchar = (char *) pointerint;
```

Comment: This is correct, but to extend, what you did there is typecasted the address of the pointer. Since `pointerint` is already a pointer, you don't need to use the `&` operator again.

Comment: Here I convert the value of the pointer and not the address of the pointer (what the OP did).

Comment: @LuchianGrigore I assume he initializes the `pointerint` pointer.

Comment: Even if pointerint isn't initialised, it will work. You'd just be copying the number across. All you're changing is the semantic meaning of the data that is pointed to.

Comment: @slugonamission a non-initialized pointer is an invalid pointer and accessing (even just reading it) an invalid pointer is undefined behavior.

Comment: @slugonamission nope. What number? There's no number to speak of because it's not initialized. Reading from an uninitialized variable is UB.

Comment: The value of the pointer is undefined, but reading it will still yield a, albeit undefined, value.

Comment: @slugonamission no, reading from it will yield undefined behavior.

Comment: @LuchianGrigore to the extent that the value returned from it will be undefined, and the side effects potentially undefined. Since it will consume stack space using most compilers, there is still some data there. You just don't know what it is.

Comment: @slugonamission do you know what undefined behavior means?

Comment: @slugonamission Not only did you post a comment in the wrong place (it should have been posted to the OP's question, where the address was typecast), your other claims here are incorrect. You are debating with people with a far better understanding of the language standard.

Comment: Ok, I'm wrong in this case, sorry. I never realised in C that indeterminate can refer to a trap value.

Comment: @slugonamission Here's the thing: in practice, in nearly all implementations, a pointer is represented by "just a number", and an assignment from an uninitialized pointer just copies that representation. But that's not what the C standard says, and it's a good mental habit to keep in mind the formalism ... type safety is essential to robust software.

Comment: There's more discussion about this at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1597405/what-happens-to-a-declared-uninitialized-variable-in-c-does-it-have-a-value

Comment: OK, here it is.  Actually the first answer was correct, all I really need to do is assign the pointerint to the pointerchar, with out the ampersand.  So you were right there, however also the pointerint needs to be initialized first, so as to not allow the compiler to assign a zero value to the address.

Soooo...what a should have done was....


//C++

int *pointerint, dummy;
char *pointerchar;

Dummy = 32;
pointerint = &dummy;

pointerchar = pointerint;
pointerchar-=3;//

Answer (score 3):

Now that you have a C answer, here's a C++ one:

```
int *pointerint;  
char *pointerchar;
//initialize pointerint
pointerchar = reinterpret_cast<char*>(pointerint);
```

Note that if you don't initialize the `pointerint`, you'll run into undefined behavior.

Comment: pointers? You mean "if you don't initialize pointerint" ... you just set pointerchar and don't need to initialize it.

Comment: @JimBalter true. That's what I meant. :)

Comment: I always love ___C++___ answers, :) +1

Comment: Yes that's the correct answer, this holds true for C as well, initializing the pointer is key!  Also, I need to subtract 3 for the final pointer to start the char pointer at the MSB in the word, byte 0.